# Create view with multiple tables and one junction table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following table schemas:-

```
table1:
id1(primary key)
col1

table2:
id2(pk)
col2

table3:
id3(pk)
col3

junctable:
id1(fk),id2(fk),id3(fk),juncfield
```

Primary keys of table1,table2 and table3 are stored in another table called junctable. Now, I want to create a view that has the columns: col1,col2 and col3 from respective tables and juncfield from junctable.

Can someone tel me how to perform a join operation with the junction table and create a view?

Comment: It isn't clear with your field names, what you want to join ?  Can you give better description.

Comment: Please check i have edited the question

Comment: Why are you doing this, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have this existing schema.. and I want a view with my required fields, I didnt create this schema..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way, using `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT T1.Col1,T2.Col2,T3.Col3,J.Juncfield
FROM junctable J LEFT JOIN
     Table1 T1 ON J.id1=T1.id1 LEFT JOIN
     Table2 T2 ON J.id2=T2.id2 LEFT JOIN
     Table3 T3 ON J.id3=T3.id3
```

Comment: Hi my question is put on hold as unclear despite editing. And I have also received two downvotes.. Could you please tell me what to do?

Comment: @Tania: You don't have to do anything. I have edited your question now to make it more clear. Moderators will reopen this question if it is supposed to be.